# Why does my Vue app not run when served from webpack dev-server?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a Vue app that is working and bundled using webpack. Now I'm trying to get the webpack dev server working for hot reload.

However my application does not even display on the initial page load. No errors, just doesn't load. I can see my code in the file served from the dev-server, including it rebuilding if I change anything.

Here's how my file is included:

```
<script src="https://localhost:44201/dist/my-lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is how my app is rendered to the page:

```
/* landing page */
import SplashIndexApp from './apps/landing-page/landing-page-app.vue';
if (document.querySelector("#splash-index-app")) {
    var store = new Vuex.Store(landingPageStore);
    new Vue({
        el: '#splash-index-app',
        store,
        render: h => h(SplashIndexApp)
    });
}
```

If I build this and include it from the dist folder as such:

```
<script src="~/dist/my-lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then it works fine.

I have no idea what the difference is but clearly I'm missing something fundamental.

**Edit:** added config:

```
devServer: {
    hot: true,
    https: true,
    overlay: true,
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    port: 44201
},
```

Comment: Is the port correct? Are you definitely serving over https? What does the Network panel say in your browser's devtools? There's nothing in this code that can tell us the issue. Sidenote: no need for ` type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: The port is correct, the file has been downloaded successfully. I can see the content of the file in the network panel of the dev tools. Cheers for the tip. =)

Comment: Ah, interesting. Are you including the scripts in the `head` or at the bottom of the `body`? I doubt it's a strange timing issue but I have no other thoughts. What if you toss an alert at the bottom of the file outside of the if?
 Also, not sure how a the server handles `~`. I mean, I know that's the one working but it could be causing some kind of delay that's tricking it into working?

Comment: I remove that one if I'm using the dev-server one. Script is included at the bottom. Alerts do not get fired. It's like the browser is loading the file, then ignoring it? Or somehow not actually attaching my functionality to the page?